# How to disable all possible popup messages in CDHtmlDialog?

Tags: com, mfc, dhtml

I use CDHtmlDialog to work with DOM of some HTML content from given URLs. I need to disable all possible popup messages (e.g Security alerts) that can appear as in case of InternetExplorer Browser. In JScript I can set property Silent to true

```
var oIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application","EventIE_");
oIE.Silent = true;
```

and that's work! How to get same behaviour in CDHtmlDialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution!

```
m_pBrowserApp->put_Silent(VARIANT_TRUE);
```